# Why does order of candles on a candelabra matter in this problem?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> How many ways are there to fill a candelabra with $4$ candle holders
>   from a box of $6$ distinctly colored candles?

Although the $4$ candles are distinctly colored, the order of placing them on a candelabra should not matter. So this is just a "combination" problem and the answer should be $\binom{6}{4} = \frac{6!}{4!2!}$

But the answer states that order matters, and says the answer is basically:
$6\times5\times4\times3 = 360$

How does order of candles on a candelabra matter?

Comment: Do you consider that a candelabra with red, blue, green and yellow candles is the same as a candelabra with yellow, blue, red and green candles ? I think that if you put them next to one another you will see the difference real quick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because "red candle, blue candle, green candle, yellow candle" is not the same as "blue candle, red candle, green candle, yellow candle".

Comment: Thank you. I had a wrong image about a candelabra in my head.

Comment: @RahulBharadwaj You're welcome. Remember, if an answer is what you needed, you can also upvote and accept it.